# How to store an html element ID as a local variable in razor pages when html element is clicked

Tags: c#, razor

So I have a list of countries that I currently have displayed on the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<CountryViewer.Models.CountryModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

}



<h1>Index</h1>

@*<p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>*@

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        <option id="@item.Alpha3Code" >
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)



                        </option>

                    }
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="selectID">Submit</button>
            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-responsive" style="width:400px">
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alpha3Code)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Population)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Flag)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Capital)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Alpha3Code)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Population)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Flag)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Capital)
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            }
                            </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user selects one of the countries on the list I want to display that information. The way I thought to do it was to store the ID of the clicked element and then run a foreach loop to filter through and then display the information.

```
 <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                if (item.Alpha3Code == idselected)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Alpha3Code)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Population)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Flag)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Capital)
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                }
                            }
                            </tbody>
```

How do I do this? or is there another simpler way? I have heard of using ajax but I am at a loss at how to begin. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is when selecting an item in your select, do a redirect (ex: http://localhost:1234/yourpage/{{selectedId}} or http://localhost:1234/yourpage&selectedId={{...}}). Then use it to show selected data.

Another better solution, do an ajax request back to your API, and receive a JSON data, then bind those data using JavaScript.

If your list of items is small/light weight, you can even render all items and keep data in a hidden input or a js variable. Then on selecting an item in your select, just filter the data to display selected item.